# Making Terms Query in Elastic Search

Tags: php, codeigniter, elasticsearch, search

I need to search multiple ids in the Elastic search. same like IN in SQL.
When I write static multiple IDs, it works but when I make IDs array and then implode to make comma-separated IDs for ES. It does not work.

Implode query:

```
$ids = array();
foreach ($this->session->userdata('cart') as $key => $value) {
 $ids[] = trim($key);
}


$params = [

            'index' => ES_INDEX_PD,
            'body' => [
                'query' => [
                    'constant_score' => [
                        'filter' => [
                            'terms' => [ 
                                'id' => [implode(",", $ids)]
                            ]
                        ],
                    ]

                ]
            ]
        ];

        $products = $this->elasticsearch->client->search($params);
```

This is from imploding result... Does not work

```
Array ( [index] => example-prod [body] => Array ( [query] => Array ( [constant_score] => Array ( [filter] => Array ( [terms] => Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => 10241308,10928958 ) ) ) ) ) ) )
```

This is static IDs passed to query. This works

```
Array ( [index] => example-prod [body] => Array ( [query] => Array ( [constant_score] => Array ( [filter] => Array ( [terms] => Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => 10241308 [1] => 10928958 ) ) ) ) ) ) )
```

Comment: The id field expects an array, while you are passing a string, so i think you should be able to just pass the id's without impolotion

Comment: @MarkSmit yes you're ri8. no need to use extra array implode with comma here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use extra `implode()` with `,` here when you pass **ids**. I had the same issue couple of months back.Just pass the array of ids like this to your `terms` query and it'll work perfectly.

```
$ids = array();
foreach ($this->session->userdata('cart') as $key => $value) {
 $ids[] = trim($key);
}

$params = [

            'index' => ES_INDEX_PD,
            'body' => [
                'query' => [
                    'constant_score' => [
                        'filter' => [
                            'terms' => [ 
                                'id' => $ids
                            ]
                        ],
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];

$products = $this->elasticsearch->client->search($params);
```

Comment: Yesterday i tried the same way but it did not work. Now it works.. Thanks :)